# Numeric Up Down in c#

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I write a program that has a "numericUpDow". My numericUpDown has the next configuration:

```
numericUpDown.Maximun = 5;
numericUpDown.Minimun = 0;
```

I wish I could select numbers from 0 to 5 minus 2, Is it possible?

Comment: ok. then what is your problem?

Comment: Do you mean "excluding 2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add form level variable:

```
decimal oldValue = 0;
```

Bind to `ValueChanged` event:

```
numericUpDown.ValueChanged += numericUpDown_ValueChanged;
```

`numericUpDown_ValueChanged` code:

```
void numericUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NumericUpDown ctrl = sender as NumericUpDown;
    if (ctrl.Value == 2)
    {
        // bad, very very bad
        ctrl.Value = oldValue > 2 ? 1 : 3;
    }
    oldValue = ctrl.Value;
}
```